# storyshots error - Could not locate module ./src/common mapped as

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, storybook, storyshots

I have just installed @storybook/addon-storyshots and followed their instruction to put it at the root.

## src/Storyshots.test.ts

```js
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';

initStoryshots();
```

When I run tests, all my existing tests pass but it fails on this file - StoryShots.test.ts with error:

> Error:

```
FAIL  src/Storyshots.test.ts 
Test suite failed to run

Configuration error:

Could not locate module ./src/common mapped as:
C:\apps\vanilla\storybook-examples\src\$1.

Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/src\/(.*)/": "C:\apps\vanilla\storybook-examples\src\$1"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}

  at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:552:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/shelljs/shell.js:9:14)
```

I do have module resolution going on in my project and everything works there. See example module resolution for my project:

## tsconfig.json

```
{
...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*", "@types", "stories"
  ]
}
```

## .babelrc

```js
{
  "plugins": [
...
    ["module-resolver", {
      "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
      "root": ["./"],
      "alias": {
        "src": "./src"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

## webpack.config.dev.js

```
const src = path.join(__dirname, '/src');

module.exports = {
...
  resolve: {
    modules: [src, 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss'],

    // fix module resolver for typescript !!!
    alias: {
      src
    }
  },
```

I just haven't set any of these in .storybook folder - .storybook/. I'm not sure how storybook resolution works or why its looking for common/ folder. I have no common folder.

This is an example of one of my stories:

## Basic.stories.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Basic from 'src/Components/Basic/Basic';

export const BasicHelloWorld = () => <Basic {...{ title: 'hello world' }} />;
export default { title: 'Basic' };
```

This is my storybook main.js

## main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../**/*.stories.tsx', '../**/**/*.stories.tsx'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
  ]
};
```

Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the one thing I didn't include in my configs above was my jest.config.js file.

**It turns out the following was causing this problem:**

## jest.config.js ! broken

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
...
  },
```

Today I decided to strip everything down, and in the process came across ts-jest config examples where the regex had an exact path, ie started with ^ and ended with $, ie not a wild match.

- https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/

Not that I thought much of it or why it would break storyshots only and nothing else but anything around file matching and resolutions I thought was worth ensuring accuracy. I updated my regex to match the paths above and ***BINGO - NO MORE ERROR !!! HAHAH. A nice stroke of luck.***

## jest.config.js £ fixed

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
    ...

  },
```